# List to appear on clicking event

Tags: html

I want to have a child list appear on clicking a point of the parent list (similar to how clicking can minimize and maximize the content table in Wikipedia articles), how can I achieve it?

I've learned basic HTML years ago, and can't remember how to do this even if I did learn it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Javascript + DOM maybe? Have you tried anything on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Withou any scripting (JavaScript or jQuery) you can't do this.

Here is example with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

js

```
$('#nav > li').click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

html:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>Menu item</li>
    <li>Menu item</li>
    <li>Menu item</li>
    <li>Menu item</li>
    <li>Menu item
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>Menu item</li>
            <li>Menu item</li>
            <li>Menu item</li>        
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/4mgqK/2/

Comment: I know it's late, but if you will allow me to be a noob, can you please tell me how I am supposed to place them? Do I have all the codes in one file, or JS and HTML files seperated? If they're to be separated what names?

Comment: It's no matter how you will name it. If you will have both script and markup on the same page do not forget to reference jQuery library. If it wil be separate file you need reference to this file too. And do not forget to wrap this script into the `$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });`

Comment: So I put exactly what you wrote in the answer on top of my page? Now that you mention it, I notice reference to the `nav` document at the `ul` tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a treeview? If so, something like [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) might be fit for your purposes.

If you just need to show or hide a block of HTML (contained in a `div` element, for example) then [jQuery toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to accomplish this. If you use jQuery, it's very easy to do this, but you'll have to add jQuery to your page. More information about basic jQuery can be found here:

http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

If you import jQuery, you can do it this way:

```
$("#parentElementId").click(function() 
// if your parentElement has been clicked, excecute this function
{
   $("#childElementId").show(); // if it has been hidden before with css(display:none)
});
```